# Select many values but display as one in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am wondering if it is possible to select a number of rows in a mysql table but display them all as one value separated by commas for instance.

So if I had a table

```
Name        Color
---------------------
A          Red
B          Blue
A          Green
```

I could select Color where Name = 'A'; but both values into one such as it would return

> Red, Green

or

> Green, Red

Instead of

```
Red
Green
```

Thanks

Comment: Voting to close: possible duplicate of [MySQL Results as comma separated list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662207/mysql-results-as-comma-separated-list) This question is asked almost daily for just about every RDBMS flavor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT color
               ORDER BY color DESC SEPARATOR ',')
     FROM table
    GROUP BY name;
```

I have added the `SEPARATOR` keyword in case you want to display something other than a comma`(,)`. A comma is the default. [Click here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Use `GROUP BY` in combination with [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
 SELECT Name, GROUP_CONCAT(COLOR) FROM yourtable GROUP BY Name;
```

Query untested

Comment: Thank you very much! Looking For GROUP_CONCAT.