# Aggregate function in MySQL - list (like LISTAGG in Oracle)

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I need function, that returns list of strings.

I have data in table like this:

```
Id    MyString
------------------------
 1    First
 2    Second
 3    Third
 4    Fourth
```

I need function like this (something like this works in oracle):

```
select LISTAGG(MyString, ', ') as myList where id < 4
```

That returns something like this:

```
myList
------------------------
First, Second, Third
```

Any ideas?

Comment: That's [`GROUP_CONCAT()` in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Results as comma separated list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662207/mysql-results-as-comma-separated-list)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You're looking for [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Try this:

```
select group_concat(MyString separator ', ') as myList from table
where id < 4
```

Of course, you can `group by` the results.

Comment: group_concat is including a separator in the beginning of the strings with anything different from empty. Any idea why?

Comment: @Rodrigo you probably did not use the word `separator` but a `,` after `MyString`, that was my issue.

Comment: @HotFix I don't think so, since I probably did a copy/paste of the code, then changed the variable and table names. But now I have no way to know exactly what happened, I don't work on this project anymore. Thanks, anyway!

Answer (score 1):

As of MySQL 5.7.22 you can also use two JSON aggregation functions: [JSON_ARRAYAGG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) or [JSON_OBJECTAGG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-objectagg). You can combine these together with [MySQL's JSON functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-function-reference.html) to get results aggregated as JSON. Unlike `GROUP_CONCAT`, there is no MySQL configuration parameter which would limit the size of the returned value, other than `max_allowed_packet` (which affects all queries).