# MySQL: Select multiple records in one line

Tags: mysql, sql

In a query like this one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `Keywords`
WHERE `Page` = 'food'
```

My results are displayed like so:

```
| Page   | Keyword |
--------------------
| food   | Pizza   |
--------------------
| food   | Burger  |
--------------------
| food   | Sushi   |
--------------------
```

How do I write my SQL statement, to get a result like this one?:

```
| Page | Keyword              |
-------------------------------
| food | Pizza, Burger, Sushi |
-------------------------------
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
SELECT `Page`, GROUP_CONCAT(`Keyword` SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'foods'
FROM `Keywords` 
WHERE `Page` = 'food'
GROUP BY `Page`;
```

Comment: Although you need to specify the column name after the `GROUP_CONCAT` otherwise the column name will become the function definition.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT page, group_concat(Keyword separator ', ') as myList
FROM 'Keywords'
WHERE `Page` = 'food'
GROUP BY Keyword;
```

Also see:

- [Aggregate function in MySQL - list (like LISTAGG in Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456380/aggregate-function-in-mysql-list-like-listagg-in-oracle)
- [GROUP_CONCAT(expr)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to edit it, I was going to edit my answer, I rolled it back.