# mysql result set from two tables commas

Tags: php, mysql

Have a table patients

pat_id pat_name
1      Raul

Another table with medicines

```
medicine_id medicine_name pat_id
1           Paracetamol   1
2           Crocin        2
```

Here i need to get the result set like

```
pat_id   pat_name   medicine_name
1         Raul      Paracetamol,Crocin
```

How can i achieve this..

I know that if i joined 2 tables like his

```
SELECT * FROM patients LEFT JOIN medicines WHERE pat_id = `1`
```

I will get 2 rows, but how can i achieve the expected result

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aggregate function in MySQL - list (like LISTAGG in Oracle)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456380/aggregate-function-in-mysql-list-like-listagg-in-oracle)

Comment: Do you have a strong reason to return it like that? Usually thats bad thing to do. If you only need to print it in application, then thats the right place to do such formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT`, something like

```
SELECT pat_id, pat_name, GROUP_CONCAT(medicine_name)
FROM patients LEFT JOIN medicines 
WHERE pat_id = `1` GROUP BY pat_id
```