# SQL join to many rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a sql Query with a lot of queries.

But i will try to make it simple

Table.Result

```
Id
Result
```

Table.ResultGender

```
ResultID
GenderID
```

Table.Gender

```
Id
Gender
```

One result can have more than one gender.
So want a result like this

```
Result             |  Gender

Some result        | Female

Another result     | Female, male
```

But i'm getting

```
Result             |  Gender

Some result        | Female

Another result     | male

Another result     | Female
```

Query:

```
    SELECT Gender.Name , Result.Result     
    FROM Gender 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ResultGender ON Gender.Id = ResultGender.GenderId  
LEFT OUTER JOIN Result ON ResultGender.ResultId = Result.Id
```

> UPDATE

I have tried this

```
    SELECT Gender.Name , Result.Result  ,
    STUFF((SELECT  ',' + Name
    FROM            Gender
     WHERE        (Id = Gender_1.Id) FOR XML PATH(''))as varchar(max)) AS test
    FROM            Gender AS Gender_1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ResultGender ON Gender_1.Id = ResultGender.GenderId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Result ON ResultGender.ResultId = Result.Id
```

AND THIS in SQL manager

```
    SELECT Gender.Name , Result.Result  ,
    CAST((SELECT  ',' + Name
    FROM            Gender
     WHERE        (Id = Gender_1.Id) FOR XML PATH(''))as varchar(max)) AS test
    FROM            Gender AS Gender_1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ResultGender ON Gender_1.Id = ResultGender.GenderId 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Result ON ResultGender.ResultId = Result.Id
```

BOTH are trying to save a RPT file

Comment: Depending on the Database you are using you could use a aggregation function like [listagg](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions100.htm) from oracle or [group_concat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456380/aggregate-function-in-mysql-list-like-listagg-in-oracle) from mysql. You simply need a group by with it and you will get the result

Comment: So you want to aggregate your data such as to get a comma-separated Gender list per Result? What is your DBMS? Some offer a function such as LISTAGG and GROUP_CONCAT for this , others don't. EDIT: Well Kevin was a lot faster :-)

Comment: Please remove all those join tags and tag your DBMS (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle or whatever) instead.

Comment: I ended up creating a small web application to handle it, i needed alot of joins so it would be easier

Answer (score 0):

Try in following:

```
DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT Gender.Name, @Result = COALESCE(@Result + ', ', '') + Result.Result 
FROM Gender 
JOIN Result ON Gender.Id = Result.Id 
JOIN ResultGender ON Gender.Id = ResultGender.GenderId 
     AND StudyResult.Id = ResultGender.ResultId
```

Comment: I get this error   _Msg 141, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations._

Answer (score 0):

You are joining incorrectly. `Gender.Id` is the ID of a Gender record, and `Result.Id` is the ID of a Result record. Hence `Gender.Id = Result.Id` makes no sense. ResultGender is the brige table you need for the join: Gender -> GenderResult -> Result.

As to your actual request: Group by `Result` in order to get one record per Result. Get your Gender list with an appropriate function (I'm showing it here with MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT.)

```
select 
  r.result     
  group_concat(g.name)
from result r
inner join resultgender rg on rg.resultid = r.id
inner join gender g on g.id = rg.genderid
group by r.result;
```

Unfortunately SQL Server doesn't provide such function as GROUP_CONCAT. It needs some fumbling with XML PATH and STUFF instead. See here: [How to make a query with group_concat in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591490/how-to-make-a-query-with-group-concat-in-sql-server).

In case you have Results without a Gender, use outer joins instead:

```
left join resultgender rg on rg.resultid = r.id
left join gender g on g.id = rg.genderid
```