# Insert all instance of values from one table in a new one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables. In table one (table_1) I have `id`, `category_name` and `category_id`. Here only `id` is set. In another one (table_2) I have `article_id`, `content_id` and `tag_name`.

Now from table_1 and table_2 I need to put `content_id` and `tag_name` from second into first table `category_id` and `category_name`. This can be done like this:

```
UPDATE table_1
INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_2.article_id = table_1.id
SET table_1.category_id = table_2.content_id

UPDATE table_1
INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_2.article_id = table_1.id
SET table_1.category_name = table_2.tag_name
```

I tried adding `AND` and add `table_1.category_name = table_2.tag_name`, but I didn't get anything so I split the two queries.

**But the issue I have** is that in my second table, I can have *multiple* `content_id`'s  attached to the same `article_id` (multiple categories in same article), and with the above I'll only get one integer put in the `category_id` for an article in the first table.

table_2 for instance:

```
article_id  content_id  tag_name
================================
21596       156         Tag Name
21596       16          Second
26189       156         Tag Name
```

How can I update values from one table to another if there is no one-to-one correspondence? Also, can these values be comma separated?

**CLARIFICATION**

What I need is a way to pull both `tag_name`s and `content_id`s from the second table to first table and have something like

table_1:

```
id          category_id  category_name
=========================================
21596       156, 16      Tag Name, Second
26189       156          Tag Name
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, so I found a way to get all the info concatenated into one from second table, I just need to incorporate this somehow into my update query

```
SELECT article_id, group_concat(tag_name ORDER BY tag_name, content_id) AS tag_name, group_concat(content_id ORDER BY tag_name, content_id) AS tag_id
FROM table_2
GROUP BY article_id
```

Answer (score 1):

this will work

```
UPDATE table_1
INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_2.article_id = table_1.id
SET table_1.category_id = table_2.content_id, table_1.category_name = table_2.tag_name
```

**UPDATE**

In oracle , we can achieve with the below `LISTAGG` function which basically concats columns based on group. Mysql does have a counterpart take a look at this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456380/aggregate-function-in-mysql-list-like-listagg-in-oracle)

```
create table temp
(
       article number(2),
       test varchar2(30)
)

insert into temp values(1, null);

create table temp_table
(
       article number(2),
       test varchar2(10)
)
insert into temp_table values(1, 'System');
insert into temp_table values(1, 'Source');
update temp t
       set t.test = (
                  select LISTAGG(test) WITHIN GROUP (order by test) from temp_table tt
                                   where tt.article = t.article
                                   group by
                                   tt.article)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I upvoted you because this does work (to cancel the downvote), but the question was not about multiple queries. The question was can I assign multiple category names and id's to the first table.

Comment: Is there a non Oracle solution? I'm querying from phpmyadmin a simple mysql database

Comment: your tag is `mysql`. I am not sure LISTAGG works in mysql but could fine a similar operation in mysql call `group_concat()`

Comment: I guess I'll have to use group_concat(). I'll look into it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the answer is doing two updates one for one column, and one for second column (maybe there's a way to merge those two, but so far this works)

```
UPDATE 
  table_1
  JOIN (SELECT article_id, GROUP_CONCAT(tag_name ORDER BY tag_name, content_id) AS tag_name
FROM table_2
GROUP BY article_id) table_2
     ON table_1.id = table_2.article_id
SET table_1.category_name = table_2.content_name
```

I am updating first table, but before that I'm concatenating the tag_name in second table, so that I get all tags for one article. Then I just set those values in first table.

The same for id works.