# How to do a proper Inner join?

Tags: mysql

I have this app where I need to do a query and have two columns.This are my two columns and respective rows:

```
Name of table1: Machines(has a row called Machinesnames and a id_group as FK)


Name of table2: Groups (has a row called groupsnames and id_groups as PK)
```

**The problem is that with the query you see below I am getting the following result**

```
**GroupsNames**  |   **MachinesNames**
       1                machine1

       1         |      machine2

       1         |      machine3

       2         |      machine4
```

**I have done this but I think is wrong can you correct my query please?:**

```
SELECT groups.name,Machines. Machinesnames,Groups.groupsnames FROM Machines INNER JOIN Groups ON Machines.id_group = Groups.id_group
```

**This is the result I want to see**

```
     **GroupsNames**  |   **MachinesNames**
           1            machine1,machine2,machine3

           2          |   machine4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `group_concat`:

```
select g.name,
    group_concat(m.Machinesnames)
from Machines m
inner join Groups g on m.id_group = g.id_group
group by g.name;
```

Comment: Thanks men. This is why I love this community, because of people like you :)

Answer (score 1):

Your query is correct for a inner join, but from looking at your expected output you are wanting a aggregated list.

Try this answer for MySQL using GROUP_CONCAT()

[Aggregate function in MySQL - list (like LISTAGG in Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456380/aggregate-function-in-mysql-list-like-listagg-in-oracle)