# Join tables with one table having multiple identical IDs

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to join three tables. One of these tables (modx_article_category) can have rows with identical IDs (articles have multiple categories).
I would like to put the values of these joins in a single column where the results are comma separated.

Here's my code so far:

I was looking for a solution but am not even sure what to google...

```
CREATE TABLE article_en AS
SELECT *
FROM mod_article_c, category_c, modx_article_category
WHERE mod_article_c.article_id = modx_article_category.article
AND modx_article_category.category = category_c.category_id
AND mod_article_c.article_lang = "en"
AND category_c.category_lang = "en"
```

DB samples:

https://raslan.de/index.php/s/cK9mxGyj9wKzFsS

This only selects one category even though there might be more.

If you need further infos just let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Don't copy data around between the tables. Create a view instead, it will always return consistent, up to date data!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aggregate function in MySQL - list (like LISTAGG in Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456380/aggregate-function-in-mysql-list-like-listagg-in-oracle)

Comment: Please post sample data here

Comment: Here's the sample data: https://raslan.de/index.php/s/cK9mxGyj9wKzFsS

Answer (score 0):

You can use group_concat.

```
SELECT c1.category_id, 
       Group_concat(DISTINCT article ORDER BY article) 
FROM   mod_article_c c 
       INNER JOIN modx_article_category c1 
               ON c.article_id = c1.article 
       INNER JOIN category_c c2 
               ON c1.category = c2.category_id 
WHERE  c.article_lang = "en" 
       AND c2.category_lang = 'en' 
GROUP  BY category_id;
```

above query will return all the articles for each category_id/category