# How to concatenate duplicate elements in a row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of data with duplicated `name` values. For Example:

```
name   x 
abi    1
siya   2
abi    3
```

I would like to output all the values for each name on one row, separated by `+` symbols. For the above data my expected result is:

```
name     x
abi      1+3
siya     2
```

Comment: group_concat something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aggregate function in MySQL - list (like LISTAGG in Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456380/aggregate-function-in-mysql-list-like-listagg-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), specifying the separator as `+`:

```
SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(x SEPARATOR '+') AS x
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY name
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6cc9a1/1)