# How to join two rows in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

This is my sql code

```
SELECT b.book_id, concat(`first_name`, ' ', a.`last_name`) AS 'author_name', b.title
FROM 
    `book_authors` ba JOIN `books` b ON ba.`book_id` = b.`book_id`
    JOIN `authors` a ON ba.`author_id` = a.`author_id`
WHERE
    b.`book_id` > 0 IN (SELECT c.`book_id`
                    FROM `book_authors` c
                    GROUP BY c.`book_id`)
```

But as you can see in this screenshot below, rows with the same book_id are printed separately. How can I 'join' them. So that the author field will be comma-seperated or something like that:

[image: The screenshot]

Comment: Most people here want sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not as images or links to images.

Comment: @jarlh the result is too long for me to type as text

Comment: @OreAdeleye then you copy paste it... and you do not need to copy paste all of it, just one part that represents your problem... but ok... What do you want to do with the values that are different ? For example the book_id = 7 has two authors ? Which one would you like to show? Both ? Only one of them ? Which one ?

Comment: Please show your results as text, not an image.

Comment: What you need is the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456380/aggregate-function-in-mysql-list-like-listagg-in-oracle

Comment: Thanks very much @COY

Comment: Posting a broken query without telling as what you're trying to do will not help us help you.  Please post sample input, expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregation and group_concat():

```
select 
    b.book_id, 
    group_concat(first_name, ' ', a.last_name) author_names, 
    b.title
from book_authors ba 
inner join books   b on ba.book_id = b.book_id
inner join authors a on ba.author_id = a.author_id
where b.book_id > 0
group by b.book_id, b.title
```

This gives you one record per book, with the list of author names concatenated in column `author_name` with a `,` separator.

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention group_concat has a limit on resualt. You must increase that by execute group_concat_max_len query.