# How to append multiple values from non-unique join?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

```
table1
name  |age
------|----
Molly | 10
Jack  | 13
Bob   | 12
```

```
table2
name  | classes
---------------
Molly | math
Molly | english
Jack  | history
```

Is there a way to get an output of:

```
Molly, math|english
Jack, history
```

When I use join, I just end up with duplicates of Molly on different rows.

```
SELECT a.names, a.age, b.classes 
FROM tables1 as a
JOIN tables2 as b
ON a.names=b.names

Molly, 10, math
Molly, 10, english
Jack, 13, history
```

Comment: [Does this help ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9456416/10457877)

Comment: Hint:  `group_concat()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`group_concat`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```sql
SELECT   t1.name, GROUP_CONCAT(t2.classes SEPARATOR '|')
FROM     table1 t1
JOIN     table1 t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
GROUP BY t1.name
```

Comment: You need `group by` when using `group_concat`

Answer (score 1):

`group_concat` would do the trick. An example with your table is [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9a1ffffa8e92cac3a62451752a7bf5ad):

```
select table1.name, group_concat(table2.classes SEPARATOR '|') from 
table1 inner join table2 on table1.name = table2.name
group by table1.name
```