# How to move ID of duplicate names to a separate column

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a MySQL table with two duplicate names, how can I separate the IDs of the duplicate names into a separate column?

```
   ---------------------------------
   | id   | name       | surname   |
   ---------------------------------     
   |  557 | Logan      | Smith     |
   | 1052 | Logan      | Smith     |
   ---------------------------------
```

For example, like this:

```
   ----------------------------------------
   | id   |  id2  | name      | surname   |
   ----------------------------------------     
   | 557  |  1052 | Logan     | Smith     |
   ----------------------------------------
```

This is my current SQL statement to retrieve the current results in the first table:

```
SELECT userid as id, name, surname
FROM user
WHERE name = "Logan"
GROUP BY userid
```

There is only one duplicate at most for each name.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could use mysql `group_concat`, it doesn't move the second Id to a new column, but it would work if you have more than 2 records for the same person. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456380/aggregate-function-in-mysql-list-like-listagg-in-oracle

Comment: Hi!  Great question!  Are you trying to solve for this one specific situation, for `name = Logan` only?  Is there only one duplicate or could there be many?  There would be different answers depending on your use case

Comment: @jarlh My bad, I forgot to remove it

Comment: @EoinS hi there, yes there are many more entries, this is just one specific example of the problem. But for each name there is only ONE duplicate

Comment: If an 'outside of database' solution is an option, you could first figure out, which database entries have the same names, store them in a variable of some sort and then move them into the other table. But how will you handle three times the same name?

Comment: @RefugnicEternium There will only be two names of the same at most

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that the maximum is always 2... then you could:

```
SELECT min(userid) as id1, max(userid) as id2, name, surname
FROM user
WHERE name = "Logan"
GROUP BY name, surname
```

If you want to sofisticate a little bit more the query

```
SELECT min(userid) as id1,
  case when min(userId) = max(userid) then null else max(userId) end as id2, name, surname
FROM user
WHERE name = "Logan"
GROUP BY name, surname
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure how I didn't think of that... your profile picture is very relevant to the situation right now

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
with cte as (
   select 
       row_number() over (partition by name, surname order by user_id)  rn, 
       name,
       surname,
       user_id
    from tt
)
select 
   name,
   surname,
  max(case when rn=1 then user_id end) as id_1, 
  max(case when rn=2 then user_id end) as id_2 
from cte 
group by name, surname
```