# Error near Group and order by while converting ORACLE query to Aurora DB MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

iam trying to convert following ORACLE query into Aurora DB MYSQL query.
Changed few oracle functions to mysql functions.

```
SELECT MIN(TP.TP_ID) TP_ID,
       TC_GRP.TC_GRP_NB TC_GRP_NB,
       MIN(TC.TC_ID) TC_ID,
       MIN(TC.FAC_ID) FAC_ID,
       LISTAGG(TC_GST.TXN_IDVL_PTY_ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TC_GST.TXN_IDVL_PTY_ID) AS TXN_IDVL_PTY_ID
  FROM RES_MGMT.TP
 INNER JOIN RES_MGMT.TPS
    ON TPS.TP_ID = TP.TP_ID
 INNER JOIN RES_MGMT.TC_GRP
    ON TC_GRP.TPS_ID = TPS.TPS_ID
 INNER JOIN RES_MGMT.TC
    ON (TC.TC_GRP_NB = TC_GRP.TC_GRP_NB AND
       TC.TC_TYP_NM = 'AccommodationComponent' AND
       TC.TRVL_STS_NM = 'Booked' AND TC.UPGRD_TC_ID IS NULL)
 INNER JOIN RES_MGMT.TC_GST
    ON TC_GST.TC_ID = TC.TC_ID
 WHERE TC_GRP.ADV_INTERNT_CHKIN_IN = 'Y'
   AND TPS.SRC_ACCT_CTR_ID = 2
   AND TC.FAC_ID in (80010383)
   AND TRUNC(TC.TC_STRT_DTS) = TO_DATE('20210930', 'yyyyMMdd')
   AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM RES_MGMT.TC TC1
                WHERE TC1.TC_GRP_NB = TC.TC_GRP_NB
                  AND TC1.TC_TYP_NM = 'AdmissionComponent'
                  AND TC1.TRVL_STS_NM = 'Booked')
 GROUP BY TC_GRP.TC_GRP_NB;
```

MySQLQuery has modified as follows:

```
SELECT MIN(TP.TP_ID) TP_ID,
       TC_GRP.TC_GRP_NB TC_GRP_NB,
       MIN(TC.TC_ID) TC_ID,
       MIN(TC.FAC_ID) FAC_ID,
       LISTAGG(TC_GST.TXN_IDVL_PTY_ID, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY TC_GST.TXN_IDVL_PTY_ID) AS TXN_IDVL_PTY_ID
  FROM RES_MGMT.TP
 INNER JOIN RES_MGMT.TPS
    ON TPS.TP_ID = TP.TP_ID
 INNER JOIN RES_MGMT.TC_GRP
    ON TC_GRP.TPS_ID = TPS.TPS_ID
 INNER JOIN RES_MGMT.TC
    ON (TC.TC_GRP_NB = TC_GRP.TC_GRP_NB AND
       TC.TC_TYP_NM = 'AccommodationComponent' AND
       TC.TRVL_STS_NM = 'Booked' AND TC.UPGRD_TC_ID IS NULL)
 INNER JOIN RES_MGMT.TC_GST
    ON TC_GST.TC_ID = TC.TC_ID
 WHERE TC_GRP.ADV_INTERNT_CHKIN_IN = 'Y'
   AND TPS.SRC_ACCT_CTR_ID = 2
   AND TC.FAC_ID in (80010385)
   AND DATE(TC.TC_STRT_DTS) = STR_TO_DATE('20210930', '%Y-%m-%d')
   AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                 FROM RES_MGMT.TC TC1
                WHERE TC1.TC_GRP_NB = TC.TC_GRP_NB
                  AND TC1.TC_TYP_NM = 'AdmissionComponent'
                  AND TC1.TRVL_STS_NM = 'Booked')
 GROUP BY TC_GRP.TC_GRP_NB;
```

Iam getting mysql syntax error near `WITHIN GROUP`.

Kindly suggest what need to be changed.

Comment: You might want to format your SQL to improve readability.

Comment: *Iam getting mysql syntax error near WITHIN GROUP.* Learn MySQL syntax - it is very different from the one used in Oracle.

Comment: Formatted Code. I just modified date function from oracle to my sql

Comment: I don't know Oracle off the top of my head but I guess you need [GROUP_CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_group-concat). See the documentation for examples and explanation.

Comment: Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456380/aggregate-function-in-mysql-list-like-listagg-in-oracle as Bill Karwin mentioned you need group_concat.

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin. Its working with group_concat (distinct order by).