# how to combine firstname and lastname as fullname in SQL with group by

Tags: sql

I want to concat firstname and lastname as fullname in SQL with group by.

Ex: Display customerNumber, amount(total by customerNumber from tbl_payment), fullName(firstName, ' ', lastName) from tbl_customers

I've researched but did not get what I wanted.

Comment: Please tag only the DBMS you use, please show sample data and the expected result as tables, please show what you have tried.

Comment: Please show us what have you tried and sample tabular data. Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456380/aggregate-function-in-mysql-list-like-listagg-in-oracle

Comment: Are you looking for `concat`?  There's no `fullName` function, unless you provided one.

Comment: this is going to be dependent on the product you use (mysql, posgres, oracle, sql server, etc). Please clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate the **FIRSTNAME** and **LASTNAME** columns as **FULLNAME** in an SQL query with a **GROUP BY** clause :-

```
  SELECT 
  CUSTOMERNUMBER, 
  SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL, 
  CONCAT(FIRSTNAME, ' ', LASTNAME) AS FULLNAME
FROM TBL_CUSTOMERS
GROUP BY CUSTOMERNUMBER, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME;
```

Comment: This query is about to fail depending on the DBMS. That's why in comments the DBMS was asked instead of just providing an answer that might not help.