# How to I fetch parent records with the same set of child records from a single table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to write a SQL query that will find all the number of records in a table that are associated with the same child records.

***For example:***

In the dataset below parents 1001 and 1003 are associated with the same child records:

| Parent ID | Child ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | C101 |
| 1001 | C102 |
| 1001 | C103 |
| 1002 | C201 |
| 1002 | C202 |
| 1002 | C203 |
| 1003 | C101 |
| 1003 | C102 |
| 1003 | C103 |

**Expected Results**

I want to see for each parent the number of other parent records that are associated with the same set of child records, like this:

| Parent ID | Total with same child records |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | 1 |
| 1002 | 0 |
| 1003 | 1 |

I have tried various joins but unable to figure out a sensible solution. Ideas please, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For each parent, you want to build a list of children ids. In Oracle this would be the LISTAGG() function, but in MySQL it seems to be GROUP_CONCAT() (see [Aggregate function in MySQL - list (like LISTAGG in Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456380/aggregate-function-in-mysql-list-like-listagg-in-oracle) ). So something like

```
select ParentID, GROUP_CONCAT(ChildID separator ',') from ...
```

Once you have that, you can analyze it in a spreadsheet, or add a GROUP BY to count how many parents have the same set of children

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `count` window function and `group_concat` function as the following:

```
select ParentID, 
  count(*) over (partition by group_concat(ChildID order by ChildID)) -1 as 'Total with same child records'
from tbl_name
group by ParentID
order by ParentID
```

[see demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/wKJY2Kd7)