# return multiple records as one string in query

Tags: mysql

```
students: id, last_name

1 Robinson
2 Norris
3 Smith

sports: id, title

1 Basketball 
2 Baseball
3 Football

students_sports: student_id, sport_id

1 3
1 2
2 1
2 3
3 3
3 1
```

This query

```
select 
 last_name, sports.title as sport
from 
 students s
left join
 students_sports ss
on
 s.id = ss.student_id
left join
 sports
on
 ss.sport_id = sports.id
```

It would return something like:

```
last_name       sport
Robinson        basketball
Robinson        baseball
Smith           football
Smith           baseball
Norris          baseball
Norris          basketball
```

I want to modify the query to return the results like this:

```
last_name       sport
Robinson        basketball, baseball
Smith           football, baseball
Norris          baseball, basketball
```

Comment: MySQL's [`GROUP_CONCAT()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) performs this action.

Comment: Search around SO for GROUP_CONCAT, and you'll find many examples on how to use it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Results as comma separated list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662207/mysql-results-as-comma-separated-list)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As suggested by @brad:

```
select 
 last_name, group_concat(sports.title) as sport
from 
 students s
left join
 students_sports ss
on
 s.id = ss.student_id
left join
 sports
on
 ss.sport_id = sports.id
group by s.id
```

Edit: Updated the group by..

Comment: Right. I fixed that. Was a bit to quick there.. Sry.