# Sql query which will return the column from two or more tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have Author(id, name), Book(id, name), Book_Author(bookid, authorid), Book_Reader table(bookId, authorId) tables.

```
AUthor(id, name)
========

    1  | James
    2  | Ivan
    3  |John
    4  |Harry

Book(id, name)
=============

    1  |   Introducing Mysql
    2  |   Hibernate tutorials


Book_Author(bookId, authorId)
=========

    1  | 1
    2  | 3

Book_reader(bookId, authorId)
=============

        1  | 1
        1  | 3
        1  | 4
```

where bookAuthor table represents the author of the book and book reader represents the authors read that book.

Now I want the query which will return me book, author of the book and authors list read that book.

```
Bookname             Author         Readers
================================================

    Introducing Mysql     James           James,John,Harry
```

Or I want all the books where author is James or Reader is James..
Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662207/mysql-results-as-comma-separated-list

Comment: You have to try and ask for help, try with join sql requests, try that: http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqljoin.php

Answer (score 0):

```
select
b.name,
a1.name as author,
group_concat(a2.name) as reader
from 
book_reader br 
inner join book b on b.id = br.bookId
inner join book_Author ba on ba.bookId = br.bookId
inner join author a1 on a1.id = ba.authorId
inner join author a2 on a2.id = br.authorId
group by b.id
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1aab6/1)**

> I want all the books where james is author or james is reader

For the above you can just use where condition as

```
select
name,
type
from
(
  select
  b.name,
  'Author' as type
  from book b
  inner join book_author ba on ba.bookId = b.id
  inner join author a on a.id = ba.authorId
  where a.name = 'James'
  UNION ALL
  select
  b.name,
  'Reader' as Type
  from book b
  inner join book_reader br on br.bookId = b.id
  inner join author a on a.id = br.authorId
  where a.name = 'James'
)t
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c6bd/2)**

I have added `UNION ALL` to list all the and also type as column to notify Reading or Author. If you do not want that just remove and also can Use just `UNION` just in case you dont want duplicate book names.

Comment: I want all the books where james is author or james is reader

Comment: Check the update. Also dont put new requests on the existing question what you asked earlier is totally different than what r asking now. So put a different question in this cases.

Answer (score 0):

Book, author, and readers:

```
SELECT b.name AS BookName, a1.name AS AuthorName, group_concat(DISTINCT a2.name) AS readers
FROM book_reader AS br 
JOIN book AS b on b.id = br.book_id
JOIN book_author AS ba on ba.book_id = br.book_id
JOIN author AS a1 on a1.id = ba.author_id
JOIN author AS a2 on a2.id = br.author_id
GROUP BY b.id;
```

I've used table aliases in this query to reduce the amount of typing. The [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function is used to group together the reader names into one column.

The books where the author is James:

```
SELECT book.name
FROM book_author
JOIN book ON book.id = book_author.book_id
JOIN author ON author.id = book_author.author_id
WHERE author.name = "James";
```

The books where the reader is James:

```
SELECT book.name
FROM book_reader
JOIN book ON book.id = book_reader.book_id
JOIN author ON author.id = book_reader.author_id
WHERE author.name = "James";
```