# MySQL Merge multiple colums into one 'temporary' column

Tags: mysql, sql, merge, multiple-columns, temporary

I was curious about the fact, if it's possible to merge multiple columns (seperated by a comma, or something else) into one column.

So for instance, i have these tables (languages):

```
language_id    |   language_iso  
    1                   NL
    2                   EN
    3                   GT
    4                   EN
```

(Domains)

```
domain_id    |   domain_name  
    1                example
```

And another table which links the language to a webdomain

```
languagetodomain_id    |   languagetodomain_lang    |   languagetodomain_domain
    1                               1                            1
    2                               2                            1
    3                               4                            1
    4                               3                            1
```

And retrieve them in this order (ONE column as a reminder)

```
domain_id    |   domain_name    | TemporaryColumn
    1                example         {1,2,4,3}
```

Comment: [MySQL Results as comma separated list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662207/mysql-results-as-comma-separated-list)

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT` will do the job.

Comment: Try using http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html.

Comment: Yeah, but how repeat it for every single row, into one column?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat group by domain_ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT Domains.*, CONCAT('{',GROUP_CONCAT(languagetodomain_lang),'}') AS TemporaryColumn
FROM Domains
JOIN LanguageToDomain ON LanguageToDomain.languagetodomain_domain = Domains.domain_id
GROUP BY domain_id
```

The function `GROUP_CONCAT` groups values separating them by a comma. I added the brackets using normal `CONCAT` function.
You need to group on the domain_id so it takes all the `languagetodomain_lang` for each domain that you have.

I've guessed the table name for languagetodomain as you didn't provide it.

Comment: I keep receiving this message that I can only return 1 row. So how will this fix the multiple row issue?

Comment: sorry i've mixed up group_concat with concat_ws let me fix it first

Comment: fixed, and i don't really see where you would get that error. can you update to see what you have now?

Comment: My fault, forgotten to mention that the data is being retrieved due usage of subquery.

Comment: have you fixed it yourself? if not, update your question and i'll take another look

Comment: I'll be updating my question, one second.

Comment: if you can export it as sql, you can make an sql fiddle or just post the creates and inserts. makes it a lot easier to try ^^

Comment: I'm sorry! I managed to fix it yes, due help of you. Thanks, once again.. too bad i can't vote you up :/

Comment: @Testuser075 haha, doesn't matter. happy to help :) you're almost there 1 more rep i think? good luck on your project!

Answer (score 0):

Spelled out:

[Group_Concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) allows you to combine data across rows.

```
SELECT D.Domain_Id
  , D.Domain_Name
  , Group_Concat(LanguageToDomain_Lang, 
        ORDER BY LanguageToDomain_ID DESC SEPARATOR ',') as TemporaryColumn
FROM Domains D
INNER JOIN WebDomain WD
 on D.Domain_ID = WD.LanguageToDomain_ID
GROUP BY D.Domain_Id, D.Domain_Name
```