# Count Male and Female in SQL and how many records are there. With male listed with their name

Tags: sql

I have a table `Company`, and I want to group the entries by `Male` and `Female`.

And I want their names listed in a column.

The result should like as shown here:

```
+--------+----------+---------------------+
| Count  |  Gender  | Name                |
+--------+----------+---------------------+
|   5    |    M     | Sandy, Loli , Deays.|
|   3    |    F     | Any , Any.......    |
+--------+----------+---------------------+
```

I got the count of the male and female, but I also need the names in a single column

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662207/mysql-results-as-comma-separated-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This but please keep in mind that `STRING_AGG` is not available on every DBMS system

```
select Gender, count(*) Count, String_agg(name, ',')
from t
group by Gender
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a command called GROUP_CONCAT that might work for you depending on the exact flavor of SQL you are using.

```
SELECT count(*) as Count, Gender, GROUP_CONCAT(name) as Names
FROM Company 
GROUP BY Gender;
```

This works in MySQL