# How to multiple rows to column & show one row

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am facing a problem with the MySQL query result. 
I want result rows to a column &  get only one row
please suggest & help to solve my problem

I Done that in numeric values using sum() but in this case, data is string not numeric

```sql
SELECT 
CASE WHEN IB.`IndicatorId` = 459 THEN AA.`Answer` ELSE '' END AS 'FO',
CASE WHEN IB.`IndicatorId` = 462 THEN AA.`Answer` ELSE '' END AS 'Main_Canal',   
CASE WHEN IB.`IndicatorId` = 461 THEN AA.`Answer` ELSE '' END AS 'Parent_Canal',
CASE WHEN IB.`IndicatorId` = 473 THEN AA.`Answer` ELSE '' END AS 'Channel_length',
CASE WHEN IB.`IndicatorId` = 472 THEN AA.`Answer` ELSE '' END AS 'Design_Discharge_Cusecs',
CASE WHEN IB.`IndicatorId` = 474 THEN AA.`Answer` ELSE '' END AS 'GCA',
CASE WHEN IB.`IndicatorId` = 475 THEN AA.`Answer` ELSE '' END AS 'CCA',
CASE WHEN IB.`IndicatorId` = 471 THEN AA.`Answer` ELSE '' END AS 'Water_Courses',
A.`DataCollectorId`
FROM `answer_water_discharge` AS A 
INNER JOIN `answers_answer_water_discharge` AS AA ON AA.`AnswerId` = A.`AnswerId`
INNER JOIN `activity_sections_indicators` AS ASI ON ASI.`SectionIndicatorId` =  AA.`SectionIndicatorId`
INNER JOIN `indicators_bank` AS IB ON IB.`IndicatorId` = ASI.`IndicatorId`
WHERE 1=1  AND A.AnswerId = 57
```

I want one row with rows to column

Comment: explain more what you want, share the DB tables and their data with expected output.

Comment: Sorry.! I haven't any attachment option I can't explain I'm confused

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/662207/mysql-results-as-comma-separated-list

Comment: I don't want to use group_concat(). I haven't the option to send you my screenshot of executed results & expected result.