# Advanced sum aggregate fields

Tags: mysql, sql

My sql table looks like:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
create table ad(
  ad_id int,
  ad_name varchar(10)
);

create table ad_insight(
   id int,
   ad_id int,
   date date, 
   clicks int
 );
create table product(
    product_id int,
    product_name varchar(10)
);
create table product_insight(
    id int,
    product_id int, 
    sale int, 
    date date
);
create table ads_products(
    ad_id int,
    product_id int
);                              
                                    
insert into ad(ad_id, ad_name) values
  (1,'ad1'),
  (2,'ad2'),
  (3,'ad3');
 
 
insert into ad_insight(id, ad_id, date, clicks) values
    (1, 1, '2021-04-25', 1),
    (2, 1, '2021-04-24', 4),
    (3, 1, '2021-04-23', 2),
    (4, 2, '2021-04-25', 6),
    (5, 2, '2021-03-03', 7);


insert into product(product_id, product_name) values
    (1,'prod1'),
    (2,'prod2'),
    (3,'prod3'),
    (4,'prod4'),
    (5,'prod5');
insert into ads_products (ad_id, product_id) values 
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2),
    (2, 3),
    (2, 4),
    (3, 1); 
insert into product_insight(id, product_id, sale, date) values
    (1, 1, 12, '2021-04-25'),
    (2, 1, 11, '2021-04-24'),
    (3, 1, 13, '2021-04-23'),
    (4, 1, 14, '2021-04-22'),
    (5, 1, 17, '2021-04-21'),
    (6, 1, 15, '2021-04-20'),
    (7, 1, 13, '2021-04-19'),
    (8, 2, 19, '2021-04-25');
```

Here you have [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dfXrNqQC6wVFYM6NTNX7oJ/5)

A quick explanation of schema:
I have ads:

1. each ad has insights, which tell us when a certain ad was active.
2. each ad has products(many2many - `ads_products` table). Each product has product_insight which tells us how many sales that product generated on a certain day.

And now I want to get the following table which will sum up clicks from `ad_insight` table and sum up product_sale from `product_insight` in `2021-04-23` to `2021-04-25` inclusive.

```
+----------+--------+--------------+--------------+
| ad_name  | clicks | product_sale |   products   |
+----------+--------+--------------+--------------+
| ad1      |      7 |           55 | prod1, prod2 |
| ad2      |      6 |            0 | prod3, prod4 |
| ad3      |      0 |           36 | prod1        |
+----------+--------+--------------+--------------+
```

What I have tried?

```sql
select ad_name, SUM(ad_insight.clicks) as clicks 
from ad 
left join ad_insight on ad.ad_id = ad_insight.ad_id 
where ad_insight.date >= '2021-04-23' and ad_insight.date <= '2021-04-25'
group by ad.ad_id;
```

But I do not know how to select `product_sale` table and products separated by a comma?

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to get a comma-separated string.

Comment: Add another join with `product_sales`. But see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978511/join-tables-with-sum-issue-in-mysql/37979049#37979049 for how to do SUM properly with multiple joins.

Comment: @Barmar but, how to sum up `sale` based on `GROUP_CONCAT()`?

Comment: `SUM(product_insight.sale), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT product_name)`

Comment: @Barmar, I have tried to solve the problem first, but I do not know how to sum up sale based on many to many relationship, could you write how the query should look like?

Comment: So you're not even going to try? You just want someone else to do it for you?

Comment: The ad_insight conditions in the WHERE clause make the LEFT JOIN return regular INNER JOIN result. Move to ON clause if you want true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: I gave you a link to another question that shows how to do sums with multiple joins. It wasn't helpful at all?

Comment: @Barmar, I have been trying for 3 days now, I do not know how to sum up this sale column based on many-to-many relationship. May you help me?

Comment: Did you look at the linked question?

Comment: @Barmar Yes I have looked at linked question, but still nothing comes to my mind :(
There is only mention how to sum up in subquery, but I do not know how to join these products which is many-to-many relationship.

Comment: Where is `product_sale = 36` coming from? You have no `ads_products` rows with `ad_id = 3`?

Comment: Why are `prod3` and `prod4` in the `products` list for `ad2`? They didn't have any sales during the date range.

Comment: I have updated `ads_products` table, now there is relation beetween ad_id = 3 and product_id = 3.
Why are `prod3` and `prod4` in the products list for `ad2`? Because I want to list everytime list of products, which belong to certain ad, but only show sales from this time range.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231725/discussion-between-x123chriss-and-barmar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write subqueries to get the click and sale totals for each ad in the date range. Join these with the `ad` table to get the ad name, and the `product` table to get the product names. Combine the product names using `GROUP_CONCAT`.

```
SELECT ad.ad_name, IFNULL(clicks, 0) AS clicks, IFNULL(product_sale, 0) AS product_sale, IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.product_name), '') AS products
FROM ad
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ad_id, SUM(clicks) AS clicks
    FROM ad_insight
    WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-04-23' AND '2021-04-25'
    GROUP BY ad_id
) AS ai ON ai.ad_id = ad.ad_id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT ad_id, SUM(sale) AS product_sale
    FROM ads_products AS ap
    LEFT JOIN product_insight AS pi ON pi.product_id = ap.product_id
    WHERE date BETWEEN '2021-04-23' AND '2021-04-25'
    GROUP BY ad_id
) AS pi ON pi.ad_id = ad.ad_id
LEFT JOIN ads_products AS ap ON ap.ad_id = ad.ad_id
LEFT JOIN product AS p ON ap.product_id = p.product_id
GROUP BY ad.ad_id
```

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ePMBVCukoTBxjNfh7Lad9R/3)

Comment: Remember about date range.

Comment: Yeah, working on that. It's getting complicated because it also needs to join with `product_insight.date`